# if statement producing 2 unintended outcomes

Tags: flutter, dart

```
                                if (localCounter < 4) {
                                  localCounter++;
                                }
                                if (localCounter < 4) {
                                  globalCounter++;
                                }
```

I have 2 int variables that are set to 0 that increase when a button is pressed. here is the if statements taken from the setstate.

The problem i'm having with these statements is that the localCounter reaches 4 but the globalCounter stops at 3.

I've also tried the below statement but then the global counter doesn't stop going up

```
                             if (localCounter <= 4) {
                                  globalCounter++;
                                }
```

does anyone know why the local counter stops at 4 but the global counter only stops at 3? and how i could rewrite it to fix this please?

thanks so much for your help

Comment: Out of curiosity: why did you put the `localCounter++` and `globalCounter++` in separate if statements, and what did you expect to happen by doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second condition wrong because `localCounter` always equals to 4 and `globalCounter` increments for each time. Try to combine increments by this way:

```dart
if (localCounter < 4) {
  localCounter++;
  globalCounter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course global counter will stop at 3, because when `localCounter = 3` and `globalCounter = 3`, in the first if, `localCounter < 4` is true, so `localCounter` will increment to 4, in this case the seconde `if` will be `false`. so `globalCounter` will never reach 4.
so the best solution is by combine the two increments in same `if`

```
if (localCounter < 4) {
  globalCounter++;
  localCounter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in second if statement you are checking against localCounter instead of globalCounter.

you may also consider this:

```
if (localCounter < 4 ) {
  localCounter++;
  globalCounter++; 
}
```